# How can I conditionally require form inputs with AngularJS?

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

Suppose we're building an address book application (contrived example) with AngularJS.

We have a form for contacts that has inputs for email and phone number, and we want to require **one or the other**, but **not both**: We only want the `email` input to be required if the `phone` input is empty or invalid, and vice versa.

Angular has a `required` directive, but it's not clear from the documentation how to use it in this case. So how can we conditionally require a form field? Write a custom directive?

Answer (score 473, accepted):

There's no need to write a custom directive. Angular's documentation is good but not complete. [In fact](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1202), there is a directive called `ngRequired`, that takes an Angular expression.

```
<input type='email'
       name='email'
       ng-model='contact.email' 
       placeholder='your@email.com'
       ng-required='!contact.phone' />

<input type='text'
       ng-model='contact.phone'             
       placeholder='(xxx) xxx-xxxx'
       ng-required='!contact.email' />
```

Here's a more complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/uptnx/1/

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, right? Just update the conditionals accordingly. If you explain what you need a bit more I (or other person here) will be able to show you :)

Comment: As a side note, you can also use a function and do more complex logic there.

Comment: This feature is documented by now: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Answer (score 26):

if you want put a input required if other is written:

```
   <input type='text'
   name='name'
   ng-model='person.name'/>

   <input type='text'
   ng-model='person.lastname'             
   ng-required='person.name' />
```

Regards.

Answer (score 15):

For Angular2

```
<input type='email' 
    [(ngModel)]='contact.email'
    [required]='!contact.phone' >
```

Comment: EDIT: This is throwing a console error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked." when I check the radio button I'm applying this on, but it does appear to do the conditional validation.

Comment: Angular2+ isn't tagged on this question. Since it's essentially a different framework, this answer isn't relevant.

Comment: @isherwood you are right. I added it because I ended here while googling for that. I will delete it if it gets downvoted or controversial.

Comment: @Iaffuste you could post and reply on a new question for Angular2+ to make it easy for people looking into this. +1 anyway =)

Answer (score 14):

Simple you can use angular validation like :

```
 <input type='text'
   name='name'
   ng-model='person.name'
   ng-required='!person.lastname'/>

   <input type='text'
   name='lastname'
   ng-model='person.lastname'             
   ng-required='!person.name' />
```

You can now fill the value in only one text field. Either you can fill name or lastname. In this way you can use conditional required fill in AngularJs.

Comment: One can still fill in both the fields, can't they?

Comment: yes user can fill both the field, also in this condition if user fill one field, the other field is not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS (version 1.x), there is a build-in directive `ngRequired`

```
<input type='email'
       name='email'
       ng-model='user.email' 
       placeholder='your@email.com'
       ng-required='!user.phone' />

<input type='text'
       ng-model='user.phone'             
       placeholder='(xxx) xxx-xxxx'
       ng-required='!user.email' />
```

In Angular2 or above

```
<input type='email'
       name='email'
       [(ngModel)]='user.email' 
       placeholder='your@email.com'
       [required]='!user.phone' />

<input type='text'
       [(ngModel)]='user.phone'             
       placeholder='(xxx) xxx-xxxx'
       [required]='!user.email' />
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Angular 2**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='email' [required]='!phone' />
<input [(ngModel)]='phone' [required]='!email' />
```