# Conditional Validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to apply a validation on a form field only if certain condition is met. Say I have a form like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <form name="myForm">
  <div>
   <div class="" ng-class="{error: myForm.gender.$invalid}">
    Gender:
   </div>
   Male   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" ng-model="survey.gender"   required/> 
   Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" ng-model="survey.gender" required/> 
  </div>

  <div ng-show="survey.gender == 'F'">
   <div class="">
    Are you pregnant?
   </div>
   Yes <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="Y" ng-model="survey.pregnant"/>
   No  <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="N" ng-model="survey.pregnant"/>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

I want to make the pregnant question required only if user picks female gender. Does Angular provides any kind of validation for this?

Comment: Careful, I was just reading about a custody battle in New York where the father had carried the baby (was pregnant). Talk about a corner case! Or, rounded, I suppose...

Comment: You can check my details answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498708/how-to-conditionally-require-form-inputs-in-angular-4/63097025#63097025

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, actually I just found the directive that does this. I only need to add `ng-required="survey.gender == 'F'"`.

The code would look like this now:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <form name="myForm">
  <div>
   <div class="" ng-class="{error: myForm.gender.$invalid}">
    Gender:
   </div>
   Male   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" ng-model="survey.gender" required/> 
   Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" ng-model="survey.gender" required/> 
  </div>

  <div ng-show="survey.gender == 'F'">
   <div class="">
    Are you pregnant?
   </div>
   Yes <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="Y" ng-model="survey.pregnant" ng-required="survey.gender == 'F'">
   No  <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="N" ng-model="survey.pregnant" ng-required="survey.gender == 'F'">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @jacoviza, I am trying to do same type of Implementation like, there are two buttons(save and submit), and on click of submit there is need of required field validation for a text box, not on click of save. Can u share some idea for it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, take a look at [ng-required](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1202). The documentation isn't good but there is some at that link.

Also here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs) that is similar to yours that was asked at an earlier date.