# How do I get required message to toggle in AngularJs?

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I am trying to set a required field based on a condition. Here is my code.

```
<div id= 'outer-form' ng-form='main' validate-on-submit='#page-errors' on-invalid='DisplayErrors();' on-valid="SubmitPage();'>
...other div's

<div ng-repeat='myItem in aFunction.myItemArray' ng-form='sub'>
    <div ng-show= 'myType == "Shoes"'>
        @Html.TextBox('Shoes', null, new { ng_model = 'Shoes', ng_required = 'myType == "Shoes"' })
        <span ng-show="sub.Shoes.$error.Text">Shoes required</span>
    </div>

    <div ng-show= 'myType == "Socks"'>
        @Html.TextBox('Socks', null, new { ng_model = 'Socks', ng_required = 'myType == "Socks"' })
        <span ng-show="sub.Socks.$error.Text">Socks required</span>
    </div>
    <button class="clientContinue" id="step-submit-btn">CONTINUE</button>
</div>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs) which does not work for me. I am stuck so any help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: what is this template engine? can you show the code in pure html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of template engine are you using on your exemplo, but if it supports adding attributes depending on a boolean your code looks right.

Speaking about Angular, looks like you'll need a custom validator (type validator) where you can pass the type as a HTML attribute. Inside the validator you'll be able to control the required flag very easily.

You can found more information about custom validators in the following link: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms