# How to conditionally apply attribute in angularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In html:

```
<cms-text required="false" id="product_name" thename="product_name"></cms-text>
```

In cmsText.js

```
angular.module('cmsText',[]).directive('cmsText', function(){
'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            thename:'=',
            required:'=',
            id:'='

        },
        replace:true,    
        templateUrl: 'cms-text/cmsText.html',
    };

});
```

In cmsText.html

```
<input id="id" class="form-control" name="thename" type="text" required>
```

I want the "required" word in input tag shows only when it is set to true and the word disappear when it is set to false. Anyone could help?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ngRequired](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) to control the required attribute in Angular.

Update your template to

```
<input id="id" class="form-control" name="thename" type="text" ng-required="required">
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be adding the `ng-required` tag with a boolean value ([angular input doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input))

```
<input id="id" class="form-control" name="thename" type="text" ng-required="required">
```