# ng-required, how to use it between input?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, typescript

I created a form with two input repeated for X elements. Each element is required only if we put something in the other one:

**My.HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="validate();">
 <div ng-reapet="elem in Myelements">
  <label>{{elem.name}}</label>
  <div>
    New Value : <input name="value" ng-required="reason.$valid" ng-model="elem.value" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Why : <textarea name="reason" ng-required="value.$valid" ng-model="elem.reason"/>
  </div>
 </div>  
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This not working as expected. How do I make this work properly ?

*EDIT* **The right solution for me (the accepted answer helped me)**

```
<form ng-submit="validate();">
    <div ng-reapet="elem in Myelements">
        <label>{{elem.name}}</label>
        <div>
            New Value : <input name="value" ng-required="elem.reason" ng-model="elem.value" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Why : <textarea name="reason" ng-required="elem.value" ng-model="elem.reason"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally require form inputs with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pivot off the other inputs value

```
<form ng-submit="validate();">
    <div ng-reapet="elem in Myelements">
        <label>{{elem.name}}</label>
        <div>
            New Value : <input name="value" ng-required="elem.reason !== ''" ng-model="elem.value" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Why : <textarea name="reason" ng-required="elem.value !== ''" ng-model="elem.reason"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can't you just do ng-require="elem.value" ? shouldn't it work the same?

Comment: Depends on how they're set, if either of them are set to number 0 via the controller then that won't work. I like to be explicit. `console.log(0 ? true : false) === false`

Comment: Thanks to you're help, both of you. `ng-require="elem.value"` work perfectly fine. `ng-required="elem.value !== ''"` block every time.

Comment: For the `!== ''`, you just have to pre-set it to `''` in the controller.