# Make a field mandatory on the basis of <select> options

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this select options in my controller:

```
  $scope.statusIds = [{
     "id_stato": 18,
     "nome_stato": "Autista arrivato fuori orario",
     "descrizione": "<p>Autista arrivato fuori orario</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 4,
     "nome_stato": "Destinatario chiuso per ferie",
     "descrizione": "<p>Destinatario chiuso per ferie</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 3,
     "nome_stato": "Destinatario assente",
     "descrizione": "<p>Destinatario assente</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 5,
     "nome_stato": "Destinatario trasferito",
     "descrizione": "<p>Destinatario trasferito</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 6,
     "nome_stato": "Destinatario non trovato",
     "descrizione": "<p>Destinatario non trovato</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 7,
     "nome_stato": "Impossibile consegnare",
     "descrizione": "<p>Impossibile consegnare</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 8,
     "nome_stato": "Indirizzo sbagliato",
     "descrizione": "<p>Indirizzo sbagliato</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 9,
     "nome_stato": "Merce respinta",
     "descrizione": "<p>Merce respinta</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 10,
     "nome_stato": "Non risponde al preavviso telefonico",
     "descrizione": "<p>Non risponde al preavviso telefonico</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 11,
     "nome_stato": "Non ritirata da destinatario",
     "descrizione": "<p>Non ritirata da destinatario</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 12,
     "nome_stato": "Richiesta al preavviso",
     "descrizione": "<p>Richiesta al preavviso</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 13,
     "nome_stato": "Rifiuta al preavviso",
     "descrizione": "<p>Rifiuta al preavviso</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 14,
     "nome_stato": "Ritira destinatario",
     "descrizione": "<p>Ritira destinatario</p>"
  }, {
     "id_stato": 15,
     "nome_stato": "Destinatario chiuso",
     "descrizione": "<p>Destinatario chiuso</p>"
  }];
  //$scope.statusIds = JSON.stringify($scope.statusIds.rows);
  console.log($scope.statusIds);
  //  });
```

When 2 of this status is selected i need to make mandatory another field that normally is not mandatory. Here is the HTML view:

```
<select ng-model="giacenza.statusSelect" required>
   <option style="display:none" value="">seleziona stato</option>
   <option ng-repeat="options in statusIds track by $index" value={{options.id_stato}}>{{options.nome_stato}}</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
   <span class="x-ico"></span>
   <span class="input-label">Note autista</span>
   <textarea row="5" ng-model="giacenza.note" placeholder="Scrivi qui le tue note"></textarea>
</label>
</div>
<br />
<button ng-click="addImage()" class="button uver-btn ion-camera" style="background: green" required>Aggiungi foto</button>
<br />
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="image in images">
   <img class="clearImg" ng-src="{{image}}">
</ion-item>
<br />
<br />
```

I need that the image upload is required on the basis of the status selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ng-required`

Here is the relevant question [conditionally require form inputs with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs)